# How do i modify onRequest body payload before send it using TestCafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I try to modify the API body request with onRequest method but it do not work correctly.

I'm try to use example from [documentation](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402842/guides/advanced-guides/intercept-http-requests#create-a-custom-request-hook):

[image]
this is my Example:

```
export class MyRequestHook extends RequestHook {
  onRequest(event) {
    try {
      if (event.requestOptions?.body) {
        event.requestOptions.body = Buffer.from(
          {
            ...JSON.parse(event?.requestOptions?.body.toString()),
            newOption: true,
          },
          'utf8',
        );
        console.log('after buffer');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  onResponse(e) {}
}
// ....
const customHook = new MyRequestHook(/api\/get-some-staff/);
// ....
fixture.only`TEST FIXTURE`
  .page(`url-url`)
  .requestHooks(customHook).disablePageCaching;
```

And it seems it just ignore it at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you change `body`, you also need to change the header `content-length`. For example:

```js
//server.js
const http = require('http');
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = '3001';

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

  const chunks = [];

  req.on('data', (chunk) => {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  req.on('end', () => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end(`Response: ${Buffer.concat(chunks).toString()}`);
  })
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`http://${hostname}:${port}`);
})
```

```js
//test.js
import { RequestHook } from "testcafe";

export class MyRequestHook extends RequestHook {
  onRequest(event) {
    const newBody = Buffer.from('Not test');

    event.requestOptions.body = newBody;
    event.requestOptions.headers['content-length'] = newBody.length;
  }

  onResponse(e) { }
}
const customHook = new MyRequestHook(/.*localhost.*/);

fixture('My fixture').requestHooks(customHook)
  .page('https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example/');
test('First test', async t => {
  const resp = await t.request.post('http://localhost:3001/', {
    body: 'Test',
  })

  console.log(`Response body: ${resp.body}`);
});
```